# Hide Content in HTML site without disclose to front user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My site is in HTML, Js, Jquery. It is not having any language to run.Now I want to integrate access level based on login using API call and cookie. If cookie set then allow to access some pages using HTML and CSS.

The private HTML page contains the private data which should be accessible after login and login credentials will be checked by the API call if it is success or not.

If some user will get the private page link and try to access it through the direct hit it should not work and redirect to the login page without disclosing the content using page view source and inspect element through also.

I tried below solutions:
1) Use window.load() function with the redirection code with default body content display none but it is disclosing content in view source

2) I have used the angularjs with ng-show and ng-hide concept but for HTML page it is hiding content in inspector but showing content in view page source.

Angular Js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

Show HTML: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">

<div ng-show="myVar">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Welcome to my home.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this I want to hide the whole content to the front user without available in view page source also. Can anyone have any idea that how can I do that with HTML pages using JS or any other Js library solution?

Comment: There is *no* purely client-side way to do this.  If you want to prevent users from accessing information, you can't *send them* that information until you have validated their access.  This is done in server-side code.  Start with any server-side development language/framework/etc.

Answer (score -1):

David is correct in his comment, **if the user shouldn't have access to the data at all, it should not be retrieved by the client.** If you're just wanting to keep content out of the inspector and page in general, you can use ng-if instead of ng-show.

Comment: I have used ng-if but it is disclosing my data in the view-source.